# MySQL functions COUNT/MIN/MAX issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, average

I run following queries for sum then I get exactly the same answer

SQL 1 ::

```
Select L_PARTKEY,sum(L_LINENUMBER) As A 
From lineitem 
Inner Join orders On orders.O_ORDERKEY = lineitem.L_ORDERKEY  
WHERE O_WEEKDAY='Tuesday' 
Group by L_PARTKEY
```

SQL 2 ::

```
SELECT sum(IF(orders.O_WEEKDAY='Tuesday',L_LINENUMBER, 0)) As 'Tuesday' 
FROM lineitem 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.O_ORDERKEY = lineitem.L_ORDERKEY
GROUP BY  lineitem.L_PARTKEY
```

But when I run the above queries with AVG/COUNT/MIN/MAX function instead of SUM then both queries gives different output.

Comment: Try some cross check, Like see how many and which records are there in both query without using Aggregate functions

Comment: Show some sample data set [*@fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) without this we can't help you and you can only have our suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have the following data:

```
monday    1
tuesday   2
tuesday   3
```

Your first query looks at the last two rows.  The sum is 5, the average 2.5, the number of lines is 2.

Your second query looks at all rows.  For the first row, it replaces the number 1 with 0.  The sum is still 5, but the average is now 5/3, and the number of lines is 3.

For the sum, extra rows with a value of 0 do not matter.  But extra rows with 0 do influence the other aggregates count, min, max and avg.

Comment: ... and for that reason, if the last argument for the `IF()` function is changed from `0`, which is logically wrong, to `NULL`, the two queries should return the same result.

Comment: yes I changed from 0 to Null, now returns the same results